# spring boot using logback-test.xml instead of logback.xml

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, slf4j, logback, build.gradle

I have a gradle project and the structure looks like this

```
>
> main (one project)
> shared (another project)
> api 
>> shared2 (another project)
```

main project depends on both shared and shared2 projects. Both shared and shared2 projects have a logback-test.xml in their src/`test`/resources folder and the main project has a logback.xml in its src/`main`/resources folder.

When I run the main project in eclipse using its main Application class I am expecting that only logback.xml is loaded in classpath. Instead I see warnings that multiple slf4j bindings are found and more importantly the logging settings are being applied from the logback-test.xml instead of logback.xml. Here is the folder structure for further clarification

```
>
> main
> > src/main/resources
> > > logback.xml
> shared
> > src/test/resources
> > > logback-test.xml
> api/shared2
> > src/test/resources
> > > logback-test.xml
```

In both logback-test.xml files I have enabled org.springframework debugging at DEBUG level and in logback.xml its set at INFO level. When I start the application I see the spring DEBUG logs.

Here is the sample github project
https://github.com/adeelmahmood/logback-test-conf-issue

Comment: when slf4j complains that `multiple slf4j bindings are found`, it also gives the location of these bindings. Could you please share that warning message?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following is the order in which logback library looks up for the configuration xml file: (from documentation)

> 1. Logback tries to find a file called logback.groovy in the classpath.
> 2. If no such file is found, logback tries to find a file called
>      logback-test.xml in the classpath.
> 3. If no such file is found, it checks for the file logback.xml in the
>      classpath..
> 4. If neither file is found, logback configures itself automatically
>      using the BasicConfigurator which will cause logging output to be
>      directed to the console.

Hence in your case, logback finds `logback-test.xml` in the classpath and logs accordingly.

You can specify your own configuration file location by setting the system property named `logback.configurationFile`.

Comment: but why is the logback-test file even found. When I run the application shouldnt the test classes and resources not even be available unless I am running the tests.

Comment: I am marking that as answered but I dont think it makes sense that at the time of running the non-test code, somehow test classpath is accessible as well. That is generally not the case.